# How to close a browser tab without user prompt and call a function in IE11?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11

After closing a browser tab, a function should be called. The message "Do you want to leave this site? Changes you made may not be saved." does not appear.

The code below works in Chrome, but unfortunately I have to include it in IE11.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    
  window.onbeforeunload = function(){
    closeWindow();
    return undefined;
  };

  function closeWindow() {
    // foo something
    window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com','_blank');
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

> Internet Explorer does not respect the null return value and will
>   display this to users as "null" text. You have to use undefined to
>   skip the prompt.
>
> > https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

How do I get it to run in IE 11?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: return undefined is a little weird, why don't you return null?

Comment: Please compare the Mozilla comment for IE: "Internet Explorer does not respect the null return value and will display this to users as "null" text. You have to use undefined to skip the prompt."

Comment: I do not want to prompt the user, I just want to intercept the event and do something in my function

Comment: "I do not want to prompt the user, I just want to intercept the event and do something in my function". It seems that you have already achieved it, by using the `return undefined;` the prompt will not appear in IE browser.